# Having some problems with Oracle objects and methods

Tags: oracle

Hi I'm new to Oracle and I am getting some errors when compiling for example:

1 ORA-06545: PL/SQL: compilation error - compilation aborted
ORA-06550: line 13, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" 
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PLS-00565: PERSON must be completed as a potential REF target (object type) C:\Users\GV\Documents\School\ex3.sql 6 1

What I'm trying to do is create a class Person that contains his personal data (name, address, phone number, email) and 2 methods one that detects if the phone number is only numbers and a nother one that detects if there is a @ in the email string.

```
   create or replace type Person as object (
  --variables
  name varchar(10),
  address varchar(50),

  --methods
  member function pNum (phone number) return self as result,
  member function m (mail varchar) return self as result
) not final;

--body of methods

create or replace 
type Persona as

member function pNum (phone number) return self as result as
  begin
  if( phone is not number ) then
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20122,'phone can only have numbers' );
  end;

member function m (mail varchar) return self as result as
  begin
  if( mail contains('@') ) then
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20122,'not a email' );
  end;
```

So my question is

Why am I getting that error on create?

And

Are my methods correct?

::::::::::::::::::[UPDATE]:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

I have managed to fix all errors but now I need a if statement to check if in phone number there are only numbers and in email there is a @ in string

Updated code:

```
---------------------CLASS-----------------------------
create or replace type Person as object (
    --variables
    name varchar(10),
    address varchar(50),

    --methods
    member function pNum (phone number) return varchar2,
    member function ml (mail varchar) return varchar2
) not final;
/



-----------------------BODY----------------------------------
create or replace type BODY Person as
    member function pNum (phone number) return varchar2 as
      begin
        --if statement that detects if var phone is a number goes here
        --if( phone is not number ) then 
            return 'phone can only have numbers';
      end pNum;

    member function ml (mail varchar) return varchar2 as
      begin
        --if statement that detects if var mail has a @ character goes here
        --if( mail contains('@') ) then
            return 'not a email';
      end ml;
end;
/


--------------RUN TEST----------------------------------
DECLARE
  a Person;
begin
  a := Person(1,2);
  dbms_output.put_line('Phone: ' || a.pNum(1152795927));
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get it to work!

This following code is a class Person that contains personal data (like: name, address, phone number, email) and 2 methods one that detects if the phone number is only numbers and a nother one that detects if there is a @ in the email string.

The resolved code:

```
---------------------Class Person-----------------------------
create or replace type Person as object (
    --variables
    name varchar(10),
    address varchar(50),

    --methods
    member function pNum (phone number) return varchar2,
    member function ml (mail varchar) return varchar2
) not final;
/



-----------------------Body of Methods----------------------------------
create or replace type BODY Person as
    member function pNum (phone number) return varchar2 as
      begin
        if(mod(phone,1) != 0) then
            return 'Phone number can only contain numbers';
        end if;
          return phone;
      end pNum;

    member function ml (mail varchar) return varchar2 as
      begin
        if (INSTR(mail, '@') != 0) then
            return mail;
        end if;
            return 'That is not a email';
      end ml;
end;
/


--------------Run Test----------------------------------
DECLARE
  a Person;
begin
  a := Person(1,2);
  dbms_output.put_line('Phone: ' || a.pNum(1152.795927));
  dbms_output.put_line('Email: ' || a.ml('armando@email.com'));

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stick with the right syntax. First you defined your Type `Person` which is right.

Then you try to create its definition, here is where you get it wrong. You have to define it as a type BODY with the same **name**. You defined Person and try to create the body for Persona:

```
create or replace type Person as object (
    --variables
    name varchar(10),
    address varchar(50),

    --methods
    member function pNum (phone number) return self as result,
    member function m (mail varchar) return self as result
 ) not final;
 /
```

To specify the body:

```
create or replace type BODY Person as
    member function pNum (phone number) return number as
      begin
        if( phone is not number ) then
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20122,'phone can only have numbers' );
        end if;
        return phone;
      end pNum;

    member function m (mail varchar) return varchar as
      begin
        if( mail contains('@') ) then
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20122,'not a email' );
        end if;
        return mail;
      end m;
 end;
 /
```

Essentially you defined the body in the wrong way. The code I provide may have syntax errors, since I do not have oracle here to test it. If you find any, let me know and I will fix it.

EDIT: A function MUST return a Type. you can't return `SELF` as it is a definition for the parameters. See the docs about it here: [SELF Parameters in Member Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#CHDCFEEE)

Comment: Your right I had persona and not person. but I'm still getting this error "3 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE""

Comment: 3 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE". On the second create

Comment: Ooh I think I get it. Try the edit I added, you need to add the `/` to finalize a create command.

Comment: lol now I'm getting a error on both return self of the methods and there end

Comment: That's because I do not recall the right syntax of the END terminator for a member function I will look up in the docs to try to fix it.

Comment: that fixed the end problem but I'm still getting a error on self

Comment: There's no `if x contains('y')` syntax. You might be looking for `like` or `instr()`.